# Compactness in the metric space of all bounded and unbounded complex sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let s be the set of all (bounded and unbounded) complex sequences and the metric on s is $$d(x,y)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^j}\frac{|x_j-y_j|}{1+|x_j-y_j|}$$ where $x=(x_j),y=(y_j)$. Now suppose $M$ is an infinite subset of s. I have to show that the necessary and sufficient condition for compactness of $M$ is that there exists a sequence of positive real numbers $\gamma_1, \gamma_2,\ldots $ such that for all $x$ in $M$  $|x_k|\leq \gamma_k$.

Comment: In most spaces there is no "necessary and suffiicient condition for compactness" that is simpler than just restating the definition.  Is there some reason you expect there to be one in this case, or some particular reason you want such a condition?

Comment: The metric induces the product topology,  hence Tychonov applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is compact, consider the projections $p_k : M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $p_k(x)=x_k$. These are continuous, so are bounded by, say $\gamma_k$.

On the other hand, the proposition that every $M \subset \prod_{j=1}^\infty B[0; \gamma_j] \subset \mathbb{C} ^ \mathbb{N}$ is compact, is false. Consider for example $M=\prod_{j=1}^\infty B(0; 1)$ and $((x_j^k)_j)_k$ where $(x_j^k)_j=(\frac{k-1}{k}) \in M$. Then $\lim x^k=(1, 1, 1, 1, ...) \not\in M$.